# Condição if em php não está a correr

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código num ficheiro PHP :

```
<?php if($debug == 1){ ?>
    <button id="btn-debug" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></button>
<?php } ?>
```

A variável `debug` é chamada aqui noutro ficheiro:

```
$debug = data_setting_value($dbc, 'debug-status');
```

A função `data_setting_value` está contida noutro ficheiro, esta função vai buscar a uma tabela na base de dados o valor do campo `value`, que neste caso é `1`

```
function data_setting_value($dbc, $id){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = '$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

    return $data['value'];
}
```

O problema é que o botão não está me a aparecer na página, e devia visto que o campo value na base de dados é 1

Comment: E como os arquivos se relacionam entre si? Todos são incluídos em um mesmo arquivo?

Comment: Sim, eu tenho várias funções entre os arquivos, esse não é o problema, o que eu reparei é que a função não está a retornar nenhum valor

Comment: pode tentar um `print_r($debug)` antes do if e inspecionar qual o conteúdo que a variável está recebendo? outra pergunta: esta coluna do banco `value` não é um string? se sim, a condição seria `if($debug == "1")`

Comment: A questão é, para que o código funcione, as três partes devem estar rodando no mesmo contexto. O segundo arquivo deveria incluir o terceiro, para que a função `data_setting_value` exista em sua tabela de símbolos. O mesmo acontece no primeiro arquivo, que deve incluir o segundo para que `$debug` exista em seu contexto. Ou os três arquivos sendo incluídos , na ordem de precedência, em um quarto arquivo. Você está fazendo algo assim?

Comment: No ficheiro index.php tenho incluido o ficheiro setup.php e o navigation.php.
No setup.php tenho incluido o ficheiro que tem a função, e no ficheiro navigation tenho o if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É recomendável utilizar `===` (três sinais de comparação) ao invés de `==` (dois sinais de comparação).

Veja a explicação aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php

Não acho que o problema seja no PHP e, sim, nos seus dados.

Faça as seguintes alterações:

No arquivo que contém: `$debug = data_setting_value($dbc, 'debug-status');`

```
<?php
// ..
// ..
$debug = data_setting_value($dbc, 'debug-status');
print_r($debug);
// ..
// ..
?>
```

E veja o que está retornando.

No arquivo da função: `data_setting_value`

```
function data_setting_value($dbc, $id){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = '$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

    print_r($data); // <-- Insira este print_r

    return $data['value'];
}
```

E veja o resultado do `SELECT`.